# How to invoke a bash script to run from another script via ssh connection

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, shell, remote-access

I have two scripts `masterScript.sh` and `slaveScript.sh`. The `masterscript.sh`  is first executed on windows-PC and one of its commands is to establish a connection with the ubuntu-PC via ssh (e.x. `ssh usrname@ipaddress`) and then invoke the `slaveScript.sh` to be executed on that Ubuntu-pc.
Then the `masterScripts.sh` waits for a confirmation from `slaveScript.sh/Ubuntu-PC` to continue executing other commands locally.

To follwing image illustrates the above explanation

So, any idea how can the connection be automatically established between the two scripts?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what yo need? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.1

> SSH remoting lets you do basic PowerShell session remoting between Windows and Linux computers. SSH remoting creates a PowerShell host process on the target computer as an SSH subsystem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doen't seem to be trivial:) I can already establish a connection via ssh usrname@ip-address. However, i don't know how i'm i gonna invoke the slaveScript to be executed from the Masterscript!